# Markov chain inference confusion

Tags: markov-process

I have a Markov chain where:

A->B->C->D

I am told that P(A,C,D|B) = P(A|B)P(C,D|B)

I am unable to prove why this is the case. Why is this as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(A,C,D|B) = P(A,B,C,D)/P(B) = P(A)P(B|A)P(C|B)P(D|C)/P(B)

= [P(A)P(B|A)/P(B)] [P(C|B)P(D|C)]

= [P(A,B)/P(B)] [P(C,D|B)]

= P(A|B)P(C,D|B)